# Georeferencing tools QGIS 2.10.1

Tags: qgis

I had created an shaplefile on QGIS. That shapefile came from a georeferenced raster.

I have created that with the CRS EPSG: 3857 - WGS84/PseudoMercator, than i converted to EPSG:4326, WGS 84.

I have open this new project and set the WGS 84 coordinate system to project. After add this new vector to QGis it is not georeferenced.

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Please add screenshots illustrating your issue. It's not possible to give advice based on the little information we have so far.

Comment: How did you `converted to EPSG:4326`?